# Собрать название ресурса

Tags: java, android

есть картинки

- R.drawable.bg1
- R.drawable.bg2
- R.drawable.bg3
- R.drawable.bg4

делаю random_num 1 до 4 и надо получить R.drawable.bg[random_num]

- то есть если random_num=2 мне надо получить R.drawable.bg2
- если random_num=3 мне надо получить R.drawable.bg3

можно конечно делать через

```
switch (random_num)
{
...
    case 3:
    {
         .... R.drawable.bg3
    }
....
}
```

но если картинок сотня, то будет огромный switch/case, так что switch/case не вариант

кто подскажет?

Comment: гуглите getResources().getIdentifier(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`getIdentifier()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) класса `Resources`:

```java
int i = random.nextInt(4) + 1;
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("bg" + i, "drawable", getPackageName());
imageView.setImageResource(id);
```